# What is the proper way to create dependency properties in user controls that allow two way bindings

Tags: c#, wpf

I say proper because all the examples I have seen all seem to contradict each other and or fall short in some respects. I need to be able to bind a class object to my DP from XAML or set it programmatically in cb:

```
<local:MyControl MyDP="{Binding MyObject}"/>
```

or

```
MyControl mycontrol = new MyControl(){MyDP = MyObject};
```

and then within the control, two way bind elements to properties of the binding object:

```
<TextBox text="{Binding MyDP.text, ElementName=MyControl}"/>
```

I would think this is pretty standard stuff, but the lack of cohesion I have seen in people trying to write examples has led me to believe otherwise.

Comment: This is how I do this, in the user control specify your DPs.

Comment: Does your `MyObject` implement `INotifyPropertChanged`?

Comment: Yea, out of necessity for other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I do it:

Assume a parent control that contains a status bar (User Control) it's markup looks like this:

```
    <ContentControl x:Name="XFoot" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
        <UserControls:UCStatusBar />
    </ContentControl>
```

Now in the UserControl named status bar it's dependency property looks like this:

```
   public StatusUpdate CurrentStatus
        {
            get { return (StatusUpdate)GetValue(CurrentStatusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CurrentStatusProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CurrentStatus.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentStatusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentStatus", typeof(StatusUpdate), typeof(UCStatusBar), 
                new PropertyMetadata(
                        new StatusUpdate() {  ErrorMessage="", IsIndeterminate=false, Status="Ready"}
                        )
                );
```

Status Update looks like this, it's just a container for three properties shown in the status bar.

```
 public class StatusUpdate
    {
       public StatusUpdate()
       {
           Status = "";
           ErrorMessage = "";
           IsIndeterminate = true;
       }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public bool IsIndeterminate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Anyone can update the status bar by accessing the CurrentStatus property of the statusbar.  NOTE to make a two way binding, that's done in XAML... within the binding directive, just press space bar and the property window will show binding modes. Pick two way.

PS: In Visual Studio, when you first create the DP just type in propdp and press the tab button, the entire DP structure is inserted for you automatically.  As a result DPs are easy to implement.

**How do DPs work two-way?**

If you are using XAML binding you simply tell it via the MODE property that it's two way.  This means that the GUI changes will update the properties when user changes the values.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ThePropertyName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Notice the Mode value and the UpdateSourceTrigger says, don't want for focus to change, update it right away.

**Wait a minute, nothing is happening when I bind and make changes!**

Three things are required for a binding to work 1) DataContext must be set either in code behind or as a static resource in the XAML 2) The pathname to the property name must exactly the CLR property name and 3) There must be content in the property.

**Can I fire an Event from somewhere else to update the property?**
Sure... the first step is to set up the static eventhandler in the UserControl like this:

```
public static EventHandler<string> NewData;
```

Then in the CTOR wire it up like this:

```
NewData+=OnNewData;
```

Then the event handler looks like this:

```
 private void OnNewData(object sender, string data){
   //setting this string property notifies WPF to update the GUI
   ThePropertyName = data;
  }
```

The other code does this...

```
MyUserControl.OnNewData(this, "Now is the time for all good men to...");
```

Comment: How do I raise the event to refresh the controls internal bindings if the DP is set via constructor or the property directly?

Comment: Does my userControl need to implement INotify or just my class object? setting the property in CB seems to have no effect on the controls elements that are bound to the objects properties.

Comment: User control does not need INPC because DPs do same thing.  I'll update code to discuss how and when the updates are done.

Comment: Any idea why the DP would not allow me to use it as a setter property? It throws error in XAML saying the setter property is not a dependency property.

Comment: In XAML you don't bind to the DP you bind to the CLR Wrapper property who uses the DP.

Comment: Yea, but its throwing an error: `The property "Channel" is not a DependencyProperty. To be used in markup, non-attached properties must be exposed on the target type with an accessible instance property "Channel". For attached properties, the declaring type must provide static "GetChannel"  and "SetChannel" methods.`

Comment: im trying to use it in a datatrigger if that makes any difference,.

Comment: I started a new ? since its a bit off the topic of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795670/is-not-a-dependencyproperty-when-using-dependency-properties-and-style-trig