# `...is not a DependencyProperty` when using dependency properties and style triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

In my UserControl:

```
public ODIF.DeviceChannel Channel
{
    get { return (ODIF.DeviceChannel)GetValue(ChannelDP); }
    set { SetValue(ChannelDP, value); }
} 

public static readonly DependencyProperty ChannelDP = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ChannelProperty", 
    typeof(ODIF.DeviceChannel),
    typeof(ChannelBox), 
    new PropertyMetadata(new ODIF.DeviceChannel()));
```

Then when trying to use my control in XAML and bind to `Channel` using datatriggers:

```
<local:ChannelBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200">
    <local:ChannelBox.Resources>
        <local:TypeOfConverter x:Key="TypeOfConverter"/>
    </local:ChannelBox.Resources>
    <local:ChannelBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ChannelBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding mappingConnector, Converter={StaticResource TypeOfConverter}}" Value="{x:Type ODIF:MappingConnector}">
                    <Setter Property="Channel" Value="{Binding mappingConnector.plugin}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding mappingConnector, Converter={StaticResource TypeOfConverter}}" Value="{x:Type ODIF:InitialMappingConnector}">
                    <Setter Property="Channel" Value="{Binding mappingConnector.SourceChannel}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </local:ChannelBox.Style>
</local:ChannelBox>
```

Throws the following error(s) in XAML:

> The property "Channel" is not a DependencyProperty. To be used in
> markup, non-attached properties must be exposed on the target type
> with an accessible instance property "Channel". For attached
> properties, the declaring type must provide static "GetChannel"  and
> "SetChannel"
> methods.

But contrary to what the error would have me believe  (that i set up the DP wrong somehow), the following seems to work fine:

```
<local:ChannelBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Channel="{Binding mappingConnector.plugin}">
```

Meaning it ONLY seems to have an issue with the DP when it is used in a DataTrigger as a Setter property...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try naming your static property `ChannelProperty` instead of `ChannelDP`.

Comment: ohh for petes sake lol, I mixed up where to apply the xxxProperty naming convention...

Comment: Now it throws the design time error: `Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'InstantiatedElementViewNode' Key being added: 'InstantiatedElementViewNode`

Comment: `There are no context policies.
 : System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.' Line number '12' and line position '18'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot re-initialize ResourceDictionary instance.`

Comment: That looks unrelated, and from experience I'd say that's rather difficult to diagnose without the proper context. :)

Comment: Im blaming that one on VS being tempermental, I copied, deleted, then re-pasted all my resources and it magically worked....

Comment: XAML resources are very fiddly. I have a shared resource dictionary in a lot of my projects, and no matter how I specify the path to it, eventually the designer will _always_ complain about it.

Comment: FYI, in Visual Studio you can often use the Properties window to do the binding.  This never fails because it presents to you the bindings it discovers.  Typing issues and naming issues disappear.

Comment: @JohnPeters Except the VS is very temperamental and fiddly (see above) and many times properties and sometimes entire classes that I know exist dont actually show up but work just fine when manually written in.